# Switching » and « in tex-mode

Tags: latex, font-lock, tex

In tex-mode, the font lock mechanism treats characters between « and » as quoted text. This is fine for French and Norwegian, which use the quotation marks «thus».

But in German and Danish the quotation marks are placed »thus«. How do I get Emacs' font lock mechanism to treat characters between » and « as quoted text, rather than the other way round?

(I'm using emacs 24.5.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the variable `font-latex-quotes` to the symbol `german` should do the trick (unless this is too new for your emacs). The standard value, `auto`, should work too, however, if the document language can be somehow inferred automatically. See the doc string for `font-latex-quotes`.

For example, put this after `\end{document}`:

```
Local Variables:
font-latex-quotes: german
End:
```

Comment: Or did you really mean `tex-mode`, and not `latex-mode`? If so, my apologies. I don't know what to do in that case. Also, I think this relies on `auc-tex`.

Comment: No, I did mean `latex-mode`. The point is that both are defined in `tex-mode.el`, hence the confusion. Anyway, my emacs doesn't recognize `font-latex-quotes`, unfortunately. Maybe I should install a newer version.

Comment: I installed `auctex`, and now everything works fine.